# ProgressDialog force closing in an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, progressdialog, logcat

I am trying to run an Asynchronous Task in the onResume() event of my Activity. My objective is to run the task everytime the Activity is coming to the foreground. When I run it in the emulator/phone the app force closes when it encounters the ProgressDialog code present in the onPreExecute method.

Here is the code of my Activity:

```
 public class PostActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog progressBar;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.post);
    }


    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new LoadFeedTask().execute();
    }


    public class LoadFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressBar.setCancelable(false);
            progressBar.setMessage("Logging in...");
            progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressBar.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            Log.d(TAG, "Checking Internet Connectivity");
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

            progressBar.dismiss();

            if (result == true) {

                //Do Something

            }

            if (result == false) {

                //Do Something Else
            }

        }

    }

}
```

When I check the LogCat for output, it shows a NPE at progressBar.setCancelable(false). I am unable to resolve it even after hours of effort. Please help. Apologies if it is a repeat question, I seemed to be unable to find any such question related to my issue in SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the entire 4 lines of your ProgressDialog in preExecute

with progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(PostActivity.this, "", "Logging in...", false, false);

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your app is garbage collecting the progressBar when it moves your app in to the background. Reinitialize your progressBar variable in onResume, before you call your asynctask.

Actually, it's possible that your progressDialog is just being closed when you minimize your app. Check and make sure that it's actually open when you start it up. Either way, your're getting a NPE because progressBar doesn't exist, and you need to find it and bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

You declared

```
private ProgressDialog progressBar;
```

but it was never initialized(not made any instance),
so that it is actually a NULL pointer.

Add this code in your `onCreate()` method

```
progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this, ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
```

will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your same `ProgressDialog` every where like :  dismissing in `onPostExecute` or somewhere else in your class. So you can simply define it as         `progress = new ProgressDialog(RemoteActivity.this);`

It will work then and you can use it everywhere.